# Mongo "Error in $cursor stage..." in aggregate pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have the collection **orders**

```
{_id: ObjectId("5e32d0fadf54cb3d81293fb3"),
user_id:'test_user',
product_id:'product_2_id'
created_at:'2020-02-25T07:04:05.439+00:00'
}
```

that I need to join with the collection **recommendedProducts** having as common key the *orders.user_id* with the *recommendedProducts.userId* that looks like

```
{_id: ObjectId("5e3ac145df54cbeca6230924"),
userId:'test_user'
rankedList:[
0:{Name:'Product_4',id:'product_4_id'},
1:{Name:'Product_1',id:'product_1_id'},
2:{Name:'Product_2',id:'product_2_id'}],
Date:'2020-02-25T06:03:55.439+00:00'
}

{_id: ObjectId("5e388da4df54cb8efb47e61b"),
userId:'test_user'
rankedList:[
0:{Name:'Product_5',id:'product_5_id'},
1:{Name:'Product_6',id:'product_6_id'},
2:{Name:'Product_3',id:'product_3_id'}],
Date:'2020-02-25T05:03:55.439+00:00'
}
```

I have read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466343/return-the-last-document-from-a-lookup) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830744/mongo-3-6-aggregation-lookup-with-multiple-conditions) posts but I am still not able to sort out how the aggregate pipeline should be written properly. So far I have the below

```
db.orders.aggregate([
 {
    $lookup: {
        "from": "recommendedProducts",
        "as": "recommendations",
        "let": {
            "id": "$user_id"
        },
        "pipeline": [{
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$eq": ["$userId", "$$id"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$sort": {
                    "Date": -1
                }
            },
            {
                "$limit": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
])
```

which should have worked properly but no success.
What I need to keep here is the last doc from the collection recommendedProducts, and only one doc from there, this is why I use sort and limit also but I get the error *"Error in $cursor stage :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit"*
Where is the error here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the form of `$lookup` that takes `let` and `pipeline`, and also when using `$expr`, the query planner is currently not able to use efficiently use an index.

This means that for each order, the lookup stage is scanning the entire recommendedProducts collection to find the matching documents.

If you were to use the other form of lookup, and have an index on `userId` field in the recommendedProducts collection, it would be able to use that index to find the matching products more quickly, and you could then use unwind, sort, and group, or just reduce to get the most recent value.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
 {
    $lookup: {
        "from": "recommendedProducts",
        "as": "recommendations",
        "localField": "user_id",
        "foreignField": "userId"
 },
 {$addFields: {
   recommendations:{ 
        $reduce: {
            input: "$recommendations",
            initialValue: {$arrayElemAt:["$recommendations",0]},
            in: {
               $cond: {
                    if: {$gt:["$$this.Date","$$value.Date"]},
                    then: "$$this",
                    else: "$$value"
                }
            }
        }
   }
 }}
])
```

Comment: thank you so much!! So it seems as pipeline was not for this case indeed.

Comment: May I ask, how can I find the position index of `product_id` within the `recommendations.rankedList` ? I am using `indexOfArray` but with no results

Comment: $indexOfArray only does an exact match, so you would have to search for the entire object, exactly matching all of the field names and values, and with the fields in the same order

Comment: this means I should use unwind for rankedList right?

Comment: If you can't match the exact document, that's the next choice.